# How to Remove the White Space below the Header and Footer in Wordpress, DIVI theme and Elementor page builder

Tags: html, wordpress, elementor, divi

How to remove the white space below Header and Footer in WordPress, I am using the DIVI theme and Elementor page builder.

At first loading of the home page, the issue happens. If we reload after a few seconds Header and Footer load normally, ie, no white space above and below the footer.

Comment: A snippet of your code block would help others find the issue and help you better.